# Where will the load be applied on the beam

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics

In a Newton's cradle, just like the one from the picture, where will the load of the spheres be applied on the right-hand beam?

Will it be a transverse load? The wire is connected laterally, not at the top or bottom of the beam, which is why I am wondering.

[image: Newton's cradle]

Comment: Have you drawn a force diagram?

Comment: I have, but I'm not sure it is correct. I believe the beam is subject to transverse loads created by the spheres, with the two supports in compression. What's bugging me is that the wires are connected laterally, so the load is not on top of the beam, but I think it should still be a transverse load.

Comment: Show your diagram then.

Comment: HINT, your wires in theory instantly buckle if put into compression.  As a result your wires are considered what are known as TENSION ONLY members.  They also should not be considered to  carry a moment. Since the Tension can only be carried in the direction of the wire,  you will need to resolve the force in the wire into its horizontal and vertical components and apply these forces where the wires connect to your beam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple pendulum with a swing angle maximum of $\theta_m$, the tension in the string caused by the sphere is the sum of two forces, centripetal and the component of the weight of the sphere along $\theta$ :

$$ T= rmv^2+mgcosθ $$

By conservation of energy, we have $ \ mg\Delta h=1/2mv^2 :$
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2=mg(cos\theta- cos\theta_m)$$
$$T=r2mg(cos\theta-cos\theta_m)+mgcos\theta$$

In your case, this tension is shared by the two strings and has two components on the right-hand beam. one on the vertical plane $T_v$ along angle $\theta $ and one on the horizontal plane $T_h$. Let's call the angle of the string from the vertical plane of the right beam $\phi.$
$$T_v= \frac{T}{2sin\phi}$$
And
$$T_h=\frac{T}{2cos\phi}$$